# CustomListbox control, how to make the items have a custom feel to them in C# (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, custom-controls

So i have a listbox, and here is what im trying to acheive:

1. have the class style adding/selecting/removing sort of like a TreeView
2. ListBox items have more than one label docked to different sides of the space ( for example, the item would be thicker, and would be big enough for two labels on top of eachother, and then perhaps another off to the side)
3. when selected/not selected, the items will have a transparentish picture overlay

**What I need to know:**

1. Is there a (free/opensrouce) control that this can be easliy accoplish this
2. If No to 1, how should i begin to create this, (where to start, what to avoid etc)

Comment: Oh common guys! don't tell me nobody has done this before..

Comment: There is a 3-rd party control that has done this. Unfortunately, it is not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a user control, and created children that draw themselves, and then just included them in my listbox, so i got it working! thanks anyways guys

Comment: How exactly did you do that?

Comment: I don't exactly remember how I did this specifically. It was 4 years ago. Basically the problem i had is that the listbox control was the one drawing the children and it was limited in functionality. I ended up re-implementing the listbox class with a usercontrol, and the listbox children were a custom class that implemented methods like "MeasureSize" "Draw(Graphics g, Rectangle r)" or something like that, and then the control would do its own draw method. It wasnt the most elegant way but it worked great